# How does one call bool.TryParse in F#

Tags: f#, pass-by-reference

I need to call [bool.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tryparse?view=netcore-3.0) in F# and I'm having a little difficulty with the compiler / Ionide.

Ex.

```
let value = true
let parsable = bool.TryParse("True", &value)
```

> There error I'm seeing in Ionide for VSCode looks like the following.
>
> val value : bool Full name:
>   value
>
> Assembly: example3
>
> The type 'ByRefKinds.InOut' does not match the type 'ByRefKinds.In'F#
>   Compiler(1)

This is the first example that I've used call by ref keywords and syntax in F# so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and the [byrefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/byrefs) documentation doesn't seem to be of much help on understanding this particular scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the main thing I was missing in my example was that `value` wasn't  mutable as it would need to be when called in this context.

Working example:

```
let mutable value = true
let parsable = bool.TryParse("True", &value)
```

This solution came to me after reading a [slightly related GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/5856#issuecomment-435429654) related to `Span<T>` and then also playing around in `dotnet fsi` which at least gave me the following clue.

```
  let parsable = bool.TryParse("True", &value);;
  -------------------------------------^^^^^^

stdin(34,38): error FS3230: A value defined in a module must be mutable in order to take its address, e.g. 'let mutable x = ...'
```

As it turns out however F# also seems to have sntaxtic sugar around the [Try-Parse pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/07/15/tester-doer-isomorphisms/) which I began to recall after playing around with this example further. This reduced into the below alternative solution to calling `bool.TryParse`.

```
let value = true
let (parsable, _) = bool.TryParse "True"
```

Alternatively without having to bind `parsable` and to specify the default value within a single expression the following example may be more elegant.

```
let value = match bool.TryParse "True" with
| true, value -> value
| false, _ -> true
```

Perhaps there are pros and cons to the different ways of calling `bool.TryParse` and other Try-Parse methods but the important thing is that I found some solutions that work and get me past the initial stumbling blocks with regard to lack of F# documentation on the subject.

Comment: Your last example seems the best to me. If you didn't want a default value, then the false case could raise an exception or retry or do something else.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already discovered, the error can be fixed by making the 'value' a mutable variable.
Saying that, the last solution solution you shared (using pattern matching) looks the nicest and safest.

If you happen to do many of these parsing operations, I would suggest extracting some utility functions. That will avoid having to correctly pattern match on (true, value) rather than (false, value) by mistake.

Sample code:

```
open System

module Option =
    let ofTry<'a> (res:(bool*'a)) : 'a option =
        match res with
        | true, res -> Some res
        | false, _ -> None

module Result =    
    let ofTry<'a,'b> (err:'b) (res:(bool*'a)) : Result<'a, 'b> =
        res
        |> csharpToOption
        |> Option.toResult err

module Samples =
    let withPatternMatch =
        match Int32.TryParse "5" with
        | true, value -> value |> Some
        | false, _ -> None

    let withOptionHelper = Int32.TryParse "5" |> Option.ofTry

    let withResultHelper = Int32.TryParse "5" |> Result.ofTry "Not a number"
```

Comment: Mabye `tryParseTupleToOption`?

Comment: I quite like `Option.ofTry` & `Result.ofTry` now - it's also nice to put them in the relevant type's module